# Is there a way to stringify JSON in Bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I know that `jq` can take serialized JSON strings to format/filter/modify the content. However, as far as I know the output is always human readable form of JSON. Is there a way in Bash or `jq` itself, to stringify the output?

For example, given

```sh
echo '{"foo" : "bar"}' | jq -r .
```

I'm looking for an output that is `"{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}"`

Comment: What do you mean by "stringify"? What will be using that output of `"{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}"`?

Comment: Mind, from bash's perspective, everything involved here already _is_ a string, so talking about "stringifying" it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem; why do you *want* to JSON-encode a JSON value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want `-R`, aka `--raw-input`, to make jq treat your input as a string instead of as an object.

```
echo '{"foo" : "bar"}' | jq -R .
```

Answer (score 13):

By "stringify", you seem to mean "encode a JSON value as a JSON string".

```
$ echo '{"foo": "bar"}' | jq '@json'
"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

Comment: Definitely value to both approaches. This one will fail if the input isn't already JSON (sometimes that's what you want); it will create two separate output strings if given two separate JSON documents on input even with no newline or space between them; and it can make adjustments to the formatting (note the unnecessary space after the `:` being removed). Whether these properties are desirable will depend on the specific use case.